# If text exceeds max length of input field, gradient color on texts stops working

Tags: html, css, forms, input, linear-gradients

I have a form to submit name, email, message. The text for this form has a rainbow gradient applied to it. When the text I enter in the name and email field exceeds what the div can show the text stops applying the rainbow gradient and turns white. How can I make it so it always has the gradient applied?

```css
span,
        .greeting,
        #contact,
        .contact-form,
        input,
        .message,
       .contact-form button {
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #ee7f7e, #f896fc, #b189f5, #87c1f1, #8ee3ee, #8cf391, #f1fa90, #f3cb8a, #f5a289);
            background-clip: text;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            -moz-background-clip: text;
            -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
            -o-background-clip: text;
            -o-text-fill-color: transparent;
            -ms-background-clip: text;
            -ms-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }
        
         .contact-form input,
        .contact-form textarea,
        .contact-form button,
        .modal-bg {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .contact-form input,
        .contact-form textarea,
        .contact-form button {
            padding: 12px 20px;
            outline: none;
        }
```

```html
<div id="contact">
        <h1>Contact me</h1>
        <p>Send a message and I will get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
        <form method="POST" class="contact-form">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="name" />
            <label>Email</label>
            <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="email" />
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea class="message" cols="30 " rows="10" placeholder="message"></textarea>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I could only reproduce this error on the name and email fields? The textarea worked as expected. Is this your issue?

Comment: Yes, and the input field on the actual website is shorter so it is not hard to produce the error.

Comment: You must have users with very long names and emails. The issue is the text is bigger than the form you entering it into. That why it works on the textarea and not the form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a max length on your form. In 20 years i've yet to see an email larger than 100 characters.

```
<input class="name" type="text" placeholder="name" maxlength="100" />
<input class="email" type="email" placeholder="email" maxlength="100" />
```